# How to remove leading zeros in DataStage

Tags: datastage

I am trying to remove the leading zeros in the decimal field in a sequential file stage. 
what is the solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easy way is with : Trim(DecimalTostring(In.Col),'0','L')